# Implementing stack using a queue pseudocode

Tags: java, stack, queue

I am confused on the following pseudocode

■ Implement a stack using a single queue. Specifically, write
pseudocode for push and pop operations on a stack using enqueue
and dequeue operations of queue. Consider the queue class is given
to you. We  will    use a   single  queue   q.  Consider    the front   of  the queue   is  the top of  the stack

push(x)

```
s   =   q.size()
q.enqueue(x)
for(int i = 0;  i < s;  i++)
q.enqueue(q.dequeue())

pop()
if  q.isEmpty()
“Exception”
return  q.dequeue()
```

I realize that the bottom of the stack is the back of the queue. So when we enqueue, it has to go at the bottom of the stack. So we must remove everything from the stack and push that item in, then put everything back. I do not understand the "for(int i = 0;  i < s;  i++)
q.enqueue(q.dequeue())" I assume this does what i am talking about but can someone walk me through it? Thank you!

Comment: Just fixed. Its implementing stack using a queue. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have already added 3 values:

```
6  7  8
```

With a queue, you can only add on the left, and only take on the right.

With a stack, you want to add on the right, and take on the right, i.e. the goal is to add the next value (`9`) on the right, like this:

```
6  7  8  9
```

But, with a queue, you can only add on the left:

```
9  6  7  8
```

So what you want to do, is cycle the *preexisting* values (`6  7  8`) from the right to the left, one at a time, using valid queue actions:

```
┌─> 8  9  6  7 ─┐
└───────────────┘

┌─> 7  8  9  6 ─┐
└───────────────┘

┌─> 6  7  8  9 ─┐
└───────────────┘
```

So, to do that for the *preexisting* values, you take the size of the queue *before* adding the new value, then add the new value, and move last value up front as many times as needed, i.e. `size` times.

Comment: @andrewwgel You should up-vote (i.e. click the up-arrow) on all answers you find useful. You should also accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark, to show others that your question has been answered to your satisfaction *(assuming it has, of course)*. --- Welcome to StackOverflow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A stack is a data structure where the last element to be inserted is the first one to be returned (LIFO). A simple queue (FIFO) is a structure that returns elements in the order they have been inserted.

The loop you are asking about is doing the re-ordering of the queue, so the element that just has been inserted is now the first to be returned. More precisely, it dequeues and queues all the other elements, which makes the element that has just been inserted the first one to be returned. All the other elements have been queued after the inserted element, which means the inserted element is now the first to be dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

Analyse how the queue changes inside the for loop. Code just adds new element and rewrites the rest)

```
s   =   q.size() .            // Initial queue: (in) -> A -> B -> C -> (out)
q.enqueue(x)                  //           (in) -> D -> A -> B -> C -> (out)
for(int i = 0;  i < s;  i++)
    q.enqueue(q.dequeue())    // i == 0: (in) -> C -> D -> A -> B -> (out)
                              // i == 1: (in) -> B -> C -> D -> A -> (out)
                              // i == 2: (in) -> A -> B -> C -> D -> (out)
pop()
if  q.isEmpty()
    “Exception”
return  q.dequeue()
```