# how to implement stack interface using queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, stack, queue

so i have an stack and queue interface based on list interface. Now , i have to create a stack interface only using queue interface without using any list or stack operations.

here is my code queuestackm.py

```
from queuem import *


class Stack(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s1=Queue()
        self.s2=Queue()



def isemptys(s):
    return isemptyq(s.s1)

def push(s,x):
    enqueue(s.s1,x)

def pop(s):
    while not isemptys(s):
        tmp=dequeue(s. s1)
        enqueue(s.s2, tmp)
    x = dequeue (s.s2)
    while not isemptyq(s.s2):
        tmp2=dequeue (s. s2)
        enqueue (s. s1, tmp2)
    return x

def gettop(s):
    while not isemptys(s):
        enqueue(s.s2, dequeue(s.s1))
    tmp3 = getfront(s.s2)


    while not isemptyq(s.s2):
        enqueue(s. s1, dequeue(s.s2))
    return tmp3


def displays(s):
    displayq (s. s1)
```

i can only use operation from this file queuem.py to implement all these function .
i just cant seem to get gettop and pop function right.

here the codes that are relevant

queuem.py

```
from listm import *


class Queue(List):
    def __init__(self, que=None):
        List.__init__(self, que)
        self.rear = length(self)


def isemptyq(q):
    if isempty(q):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def enqueue(q, x):
    q.rear= q.rear + 1
    insert(q, q.rear, x)



def dequeue(q):
    if isemptyq(q):
        print("Dequeue error, queue underflow!!!\n")
        return -1
    else:
        tmp = get(q, 1)
        delete(q, 1)
        q.rear = q.rear - 1
        return tmp    



def getfront(q):
    if isemptyq(q):
        print("Getfront error, queue underflow!!!\n")
        return -1
    else:
        tmp = get(q, 1)
        return tmp


def displayq(q):
    display(q)
```

listm.py

```
class List:
    def __init__(self, extlist=None):
        if extlist is None:
                    self.inlist = []
        else:
            self.inlist = extlist


def length(L):
    return len(L.inlist)


def isempty(L):
    if len(L.inlist)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get(L, i):
    if isempty(L):
        print("The get() is unsuccessful!")
        print("The list is empty!")
        return -1
    elif (i<1) or (i>length(L)):
        print("The get() is unsuccessful!")
        print("The index given is out of range!")
        return -1
    else:
        return(L.inlist[i-1])

def locatebyvalue(L, x):
    position = 1
    for item in L.inlist:
        if x == item:
            return position
        else:
            position = position+1
    return -1        

def locatebyid(L, idd):
    position = 1
    for item in L.inlist:
        if item.id == idd:
            return position
        else:
            position = position+1
    return -1        

def insert(L, i, x):
    if (i<1) or (i>length(L)+1):
        print("The insert() is unsuccessful!")
        print("The index given is out of range!")

    else: 
        L.inlist.insert(i-1, x)

def delete(L, i):
    if isempty(L):
        print("The delete() is unsuccessful!")
        print("The list is empty!")
        return
    elif (i<1) or (i>length(L)):
        print("The delete() is unsuccessful!")
        print("The index given is out of range!")
        return
    else: 
        del L.inlist[i-1]


def display(L):
    print(L.inlist)
```

stackm.py

```
from listm import *

class Stack(List):
    def __init__(self, stk=None):
        List.__init__(self, stk)
        self.top = 0


def isemptys(s):
    if isempty(s):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def push(s, x):
    s.top = s.top + 1
    insert(s, s.top, x)



def pop(s):
    if isemptys(s):
        print("Pop error, stack underflow!!!\n")
        return -1
    else:
        tmp = get(s, s.top)
        delete(s, s.top)
        s.top = s.top - 1
        return tmp    



def gettop(s):
    if isemptys(s):
        print("Gettop error, stack underflow!!!\n")
        return -1
    else:
        tmp = get(s, s.top)
        return tmp


def displays(s):
    display(s)
```

And i use this file to run queuestackm.py

qstest.py

```
from queuestackm import *

def main():
    qs = Stack()
    if(isemptys(qs)):
        print("The stack is empty now.")
    else:
        print("The stack is not empty now.")    
    push(qs, "a")
    push(qs, "b")
    push(qs, "c")
    print("The push operations has been performed three times.")    
    if(isemptys(qs)):
        print("The stack is empty now.")
    else:
        print("The stack is not empty now.")    
    top = gettop(qs)
    print(f"Now, the top element is '{top}'.")
    print("Now, the stack is containing ", end="")
    displays(qs)
    pop(qs)
    de = pop(qs)
    print("The pop operations has been performed two times.")   
    print(f"The last popped element is '{de}'.")    
    push(qs, "d")
    push(qs, "e")
    top = gettop(qs)
    print(f"Now, the top element is '{top}'.")
    print("Now, the stack is containing ", end="")
    displays(qs)


main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a bit broad--there's a lot of code here and a problem description, but what exactly do you need here? Best I can do is offer a dupe since it's sort of a [solved problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-a-stack-using-single-queue/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing stack using a queue pseudocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850235/implementing-stack-using-a-queue-pseudocode)

Comment: I just want to know how to get the top value of the queue using only stack operations , I keep getting the front value instead for the top value @ggorlen

Comment: OK, do the links explain this? As an aside, I strongly recommend removing prints from your functions. If your function has a problem, raise an error or return a sentinel value.

Comment: I’m new to python so I don’t really get other platform coding , but I’m trying to understand them . @ggorlen

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't worry about Python, just focus on the operations you have available: push and pop for stack and enqueue and dequeue for queue. Try working it out on a sheet of paper and only think about Python implementation once you've convinced yourself of the merit of a particular algorithm. As another aside, your `def`s could be class methods that accept a `self` parameter so you can call `my_queue.dequeue()` instead of `dequeue(queue)`, which is not object-oriented or idiomatic for Python.

Comment: Will do ! @ggorlen

Comment: You need to ask your question right. Are you asking how to implement interface in python? There are more code than a question. Please consider revising your question.